# Swift gamedev options for linux

Tags: linux, swift

I recently tried out Swift. I found it to be awesome. But I'm unable to find any libraries for game development as I'm on Linux. Everything seems to be made for MacOS & iOS development.

There were one or two SDL bindings on Github. But they were not ready for 'public consumption' as listed on their pages. An option is to use Glfw. But then I would have to use OpenGL for everything.

Is there any game development library you know? Even simple to use graphics libraries will be helpful to me.

If possible, please make a list of useful gamedev related libraries you know of in Swift. Thanks!

EDIT: Please don't list MacOS only libraries. As I said before, I'm a Linux user and am looking for libraries that I can use on Linux.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful to you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122189/introduction-to-open-source-swift-on-linux

Comment: @DomnallAust Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't list any libraries. I already went through it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GD.SE! Your question is off topic because it does not fit well in the Q&A model that we have here ("which technology to use" is too open-ended and discussion oriented). You can read more about it in the [help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I think forums like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net/index) are better suited for this type of question. When you have specific questions, please do come back and ask them here :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thanks for your suggestions. I really appreciate them. But I think it does fit into the constructive subjective questions format if only slightly. As of now, there is literally no source I know of which lists any game dev library for swift on linux. So, all the answers are going to be pretty short, concise & useful for all those who are new to swift on linux.

Comment: The [rules](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) suggest to not ask questions where "every answer is equally valid", and what's [on topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  states that the site is not about "which technology to use for your game idea". Both of these mean that the site is not about being a directory for available technologies, unfortunately. This type of question is not that good in the long term because technologies die at some point, making content no longer relevant.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Ok thanks. I understand. Is there a SE branch that suggests such things? Just curious...

Comment: I don't think asking for list of things fits any of the stack I know of, but I don't know them all.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thank you for taking out time for helping me. :) I'll try my luck at GDNet.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing any serious Swift programming on Linux yet -- it is still *really* buggy (much worse than it was on OS X a few years ago), and many things in Foundation are still unimplemented.  It should be fine in a couple years though.

Comment: @NobodyNada Thanks for your opinion. I'll keep making small things with Swift till it matures on Linux. For now, I think I'll go with Scheme & Javascript :)